# What is wrong in this Update query which tried to update table using concat() fun

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to update the field with appending data into it, but it is giving an error, please correct me (Query and Table desc are below)

I tried to fire UPDATE command with CONCAT () FUNCTION in SQL.

```
update products a
    set a.des = (select concat((select b.des from products b limit 1) ,' one okay') from a)
    where a.p_id = 1;
```

I have used MySQL,
Table Description:
mysql> desc products;

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default      | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
| p_id    | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | 0            |       |
| p_name  | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL         |       |
| p_price | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL         |       |
| cat_id  | int(3)      | YES  | MUL | NULL         |       |
| des     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | Good         |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
```

Expected Output : 
mysql> select * from products;

```
+------+--------+---------+--------+---------------+
| p_id | p_name | p_price | cat_id | des           |
+------+--------+---------+--------+---------------+
|    1 | Mouse  |     150 |      3 | Good one okay |
|    2 | LAN    |      50 |      4 | Good          |
+------+--------+---------+--------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Output Came :

> ```
> Error -
> update products a set a.des = 
>   (select concat((select b.des from products b limit 1) ,' one okay') 
>    from a) where a.p_id = 1   Error Code: 1146. Table 'test.a' doesn't exist  0.437 sec
> ```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not allow you to reference the table being updated in the rest of the `update` statement, as a general rule.

The normal work-around is to phrase this as a `JOIN`:

```
update products p cross join
       (select * from products limit 1) arbitrary
    set p.des = concat(arbitrary.des, ' one okay')
    where p.p_id = 1;
```

Note the use of the alias `arbitrary`.  You are using `limit` with no `order by` so you are getting an arbitrary description.

If you just want to append a string to the existing description, then you want the simpler:

```
update products p
    set p.des = concat(p.des, ' one okay')
    where p.p_id = 1;
```